# How to open .obj file in android

Tags: android, file, .obj

I have been using the code from the following link.

https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android

The code runs but the file is not getting opened.

It waits for a while and shows an popup box to close the application since it is taking a lot of time to load..

I have placed the .obj file and .mtl file in the corresponding folder.

Can any one say why it is happening..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attach your .obj file please. Show your code.

Comment: Thanks for responding... The source code is downloaded from github which I menstioned the link above. This is the link of the .OBJ file "http://storage2.turbosquid.com/Download/index.php?ID=394290_3163684"

Comment: Still need your code to see how you're using the library.

Comment: Also what does `logcat` say?